# Spring Data JPA / Hibernate fetch child conditionally

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 classes.

Parent :

```
public class Cart {
 private int id;

 @OneToMany(targetEntity = Items.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="cart_id")
 private List<Items> items;
}
```

Child :

```
public class Items {
 private int id;
 private int itemId;
 private Boolean isActive;
}
```

Now when i return `Cart` class, all items which are mapped by fk are getting returned which is perfect.

But, now i need to pull items where `isActive` is `true`.

Tried checking isActive in setter of cart class but dosen't seems to be working.

What should be the standard way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the relationship bi-directional and query it from Child/ChildRepository.

```
public ChildRepository extends JpaRepository{
  List<Items> findByActiveTrue();
}
```

Querying it this way gives you much more flexibility than querying from the parent. Now you can filter, sort and paginate dynamically, when the need arises.

If the condition is static you could use `@Where(clause = "isActive=true")`

Comment: Agree, But if there is any way to can keep relationship Uni-directional and fetch children conditionally ?

Comment: If the condition is static you could use `@Where(clause = "isActive=true")`

Comment: This is what i was looking for, Works. Include this in answer also.

Answer (score 2):

Use a JPQL or HQL like this:

```
List<Item> items = em.createQuery("SELECT i.* FROM Cart c LEFT JOIN c.items WHERE c.id=:cid", Item.class).setParameter("cid",cartId).getResultList();
```